# How to add as many instances of a Pane defined in a separate fxml file as there are entries in a HashMap into a ScrollPane?

Tags: javafx, hashmap, scrollpane, pane

The Pane (pane - fxml: deadline-example.fxml) has elements (Labels & a pie chart) that are set based on a specific instance of the Deadline class. I also have another scene (deadline-menu.fxml) that contains a ScrollPane. The idea is that there is a hashmap (DLList) containing X elements of the Deadline class along with its id. The solution logic that I am envisioning is:

have a for-each loop iterate over each element of DLList -> use the attribute of the particular Deadline instance to set the labels of pane -> store the pane in a data structure -> display the instances in the ScrollPane of deadline-menu.fxml using the data structure

The key here is that the number of Deadline instances in DLList is variable, so I can't predefine a number of Panes for use. My initial idea is to define each Pane and store the pane into a separate hashmap (DLPaneList), and then pass it back to DLMenuController.java to finally display its contents onto the ScrollPane and that has failed. I want to know the issues with my approach, as well as another approach that I can use. Thanks.

**deadline-example.fxml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.chart.PieChart?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<Pane fx:id="pane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="280.0" prefWidth="900.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/20.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <Rectangle arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="WHITE" height="247.0" layoutX="27.0" layoutY="26.0" stroke="BLACK" strokeType="INSIDE" width="867.0" />
      <Label fx:id="name" layoutX="37.0" layoutY="34.0" prefHeight="45.0" prefWidth="298.0" text="name">
         <font>
            <Font size="30.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label fx:id="onTimeLabel" layoutX="37.0" layoutY="95.0" prefHeight="45.0" prefWidth="298.0" text="On time:">
         <font>
            <Font size="20.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label fx:id="lateLabel" layoutX="37.0" layoutY="140.0" prefHeight="45.0" prefWidth="298.0" text="Late:">
         <font>
            <Font size="20.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label fx:id="naLabel" layoutX="37.0" layoutY="186.0" prefHeight="45.0" prefWidth="298.0" text="N/A:">
         <font>
            <Font size="20.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <PieChart fx:id="deadlineChart" layoutX="463.0" layoutY="38.0" prefHeight="223.0" prefWidth="417.0" />
   </children>
</Pane>
```

**deadline-menu.fxml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<Pane fx:id="DLMenuPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="540.0" prefWidth="960.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/20.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.example.ia_real.DLMenuController">
   <children>
      <ChoiceBox fx:id="timeDropDown" layoutX="20.0" layoutY="22.0" prefWidth="150.0" style="-fx-background-color: lightgray;" />
      <ChoiceBox fx:id="limitDropDown" layoutX="185.0" layoutY="22.0" prefWidth="150.0" style="-fx-background-color: lightgray;" />
      <ScrollPane fx:id="scrollPane" layoutY="70.0" prefHeight="471.0" prefWidth="960.0">
         <content>
            <VBox fx:id="DLVBox" prefHeight="468.0" prefWidth="957.0" />
         </content>
      </ScrollPane>
   </children>
</Pane>
```

**DLMenuController.java: (controller of deadline-menu.fxml)**

```
package com.example.ia_real;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.*;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollBar;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Set;
import javafx.util.*;
import org.apache.poi.*;

public class DLMenuController extends Controller{
    @FXML
    public Pane DLMenuPane;
    @FXML
    private ChoiceBox<String> timeDropDown;
    ObservableList<String> timeList = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Recent","Chronological");
    @FXML
    private ChoiceBox<String> limitDropDown;
    ObservableList<String> limitList = FXCollections.observableArrayList("All","Subject","Term");
    @FXML
    private VBox DLVBox;

    @FXML
    private ScrollPane scrollPane;


    public DLMenuController() throws IOException {}

    public void init() throws IOException {
        timeDropDown.setItems(timeList);
        timeDropDown.setValue("Recent");

        limitDropDown.setItems(limitList);
        limitDropDown.setValue("All");

        DeadlineController dlcontroller = new DeadlineController();
        HashMap<Integer, Pane> paneList = dlcontroller.createPaneList();

        for (Map.Entry<Integer, Pane> entry : paneList.entrySet()) {
            FXMLLoader loaderMenu = new FXMLLoader(Controller.class.getResource("deadline-exaample.fxml"));
            Parent root = loaderMenu.load();
            DLVBox.getChildren().add(root);
        }
    }
}
```

**DeadlineController.java: (Controller of deadline-example.fxml)**

```
package com.example.ia_real;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.PieChart;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import javafx.animation.*;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class DeadlineController {
    @FXML
    public Pane pane;
    @FXML
    private Label name;
    @FXML
    private Label onTimeLabel;
    @FXML
    private Label lateLabel;
    @FXML
    private Label naLabel;
    @FXML
    private PieChart deadlineChart;

    private String path;
    private File sheet;

    public DeadlineController() throws IOException {}

    public void passPath(String path) {
        this.path = path;
        this.sheet = new File(path);
    }

    Deadline dl = new Deadline(path);
    HashMap<Integer, Deadline> DLList = dl.createDLs();

    public HashMap<Integer, Pane> createPaneList() {
        HashMap<Integer, Pane> DLPaneList = new HashMap<>();
        Controller controller = new Controller();

        for(Map.Entry<Integer, Deadline> entry : DLList.entrySet()) {
            Deadline current = entry.getValue();

            name.setText(current.getName());
            onTimeLabel.setText(String.valueOf(current.getOnTime()));
            lateLabel.setText(String.valueOf(current.getLate()));
            naLabel.setText(String.valueOf(current.getNa()));

            assert current != null;
            controller.setPieChart(current, deadlineChart);
            DLPaneList.put(current.getID(), pane);
        }

        return DLPaneList;
    }


}
```

**Deadline.java:**

```
package com.example.ia_real;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import org.apache.poi.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFColor;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Objects;

public class Deadline {

    private File sheet;
    private String path;
    private Sheet deadlines;


    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String subject;
    private int onTime;
    private int late;
    private int na;


    public Deadline(String path) throws IOException {
        this.path = path;
        this.sheet = new File(path);
        FileInputStream fisDL = new FileInputStream(sheet);
        Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fisDL);
        deadlines = wb.getSheetAt(1);

        wb.close();
        fisDL.close();
    }


    public void setID(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setSubject(String subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
    }

    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }

    public void setDLStats(int col) throws IOException {
        FileInputStream fisDB = new FileInputStream(sheet);
        Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fisDB);

        String onTimeColor = "00B050";
        String lateColor = "FFFF00";
        String naColor = "FF0000";
        String cellColor;
        int onTime = 0;
        int late = 0;
        int na = 0;

        for (Row row : deadlines) {
            Cell cell = row.getCell(col);
            //CellStyle cellStyle = cell.getCellStyle();
            String yn = cell.getStringCellValue();

            if (yn.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
                onTime+=1;
            }
            else if (yn.equalsIgnoreCase("l")) {
                late+=1;
            }
            else if (yn.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
                na+=1;
            }


        }
        this.onTime = onTime;
        this.late = late;
        this.na = na;

        wb.close();
        fisDB.close();
    }


    public HashMap<Integer, Deadline> createDLs() throws IOException {
        int col = 2;
        int id = 1;

        HashMap<Integer, Deadline> deadlineMap = new HashMap<>();
        Row row = deadlines.getRow(0);         // gets row w/ index 0 (row 1)
        Cell currentCell = row.getCell(col);      // gets cell w/ index 2 (C1)
        boolean cellEmpty = (currentCell == null || currentCell.getCellType() == CellType.BLANK);

        while (!cellEmpty) {
            //creates new Deadline instance
            Deadline dl = new Deadline(path);
            //sets ID
            dl.setID(id);

            //sets name
            dl.setName(currentCell.getStringCellValue());

            dl.setDLStats(col);
            deadlineMap.put(id, dl);

            col += 1;
            id += 1;
            currentCell = row.getCell(col);
            cellEmpty = (currentCell == null || currentCell.getCellType() == CellType.BLANK);
        }

        return deadlineMap;
    }
    public int getID() {
        return id;
    }

    public int getOnTime() {
        return onTime;
    }

    public int getLate() {
        return late;
    }

    public int getNa() {
        return na;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }


}
```

**Stack trace:**

```
C:\Users\PC\.jdks\openjdk-20.0.2\bin\java.exe "-javaagent:D:\_IntelliJ\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2023.1.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=57793:D:\_IntelliJ\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2023.1.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stdout.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stderr.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Users\PC\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-controls\20\javafx-controls-20.jar;C:\Users\PC\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-graphics\20\javafx-graphics-20.jar;C:\Users\PC\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-base\20\javafx-base-20.jar;C:\Users\PC\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-fxml\20\javafx-fxml-20.jar;C:\Users\PC\.m2\repository\com\github\virtuald\curvesapi\1.07\curvesapi-1.07.jar;D:\Apache POI\poi-bin-5.2.3\ooxml-lib\commons-logging-1.2.jar;D:\Apache POI\poi-bin-5.2.3\ooxml-lib\curvesapi-1.07.jar;D:\Apache POI\poi-bin-5.2.3\ooxml-lib\jakarta.activation-2.0.1.jar;D:\Apache POI\poi-bin-5.2.3\ooxml-lib\jakarta.xml.bind-api-3.0.1.jar;D:\Apache POI\poi-bin-5.2.3\ooxml-lib\slf4j-api-1.7.36.jar;D:\Apache POI\poi-bin-5.2.3\poi-examples-5.2.3.jar;D:\Apache POI\poi-bin-5.2.3\poi-excelant-5.2.3.jar" -p "C:\Users\PC\.m2\repository\org\apache\poi\poi-ooxml-lite\5.2.3\poi-ooxml-lite-5.2.3.jar;D:\Apache POI\poi-bin-5.2.3\poi-ooxml-full-5.2.3.jar;D:\Apache POI\poi-bin-5.2.3\poi-ooxml-lite-5.2.3.jar;C:\Users\PC\.m2\repository\org\apache\poi\poi-ooxml\5.2.3\poi-ooxml-5.2.3.jar;D:\Apache POI\poi-bin-5.2.3\poi-ooxml-5.2.3.jar;C:\Users\PC\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-graphics\20\javafx-graphics-20-win.jar;C:\Users\PC\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-fxml\20\javafx-fxml-20-win.jar;C:\Users\PC\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.18.0\log4j-api-2.18.0.jar;D:\Apache POI\poi-bin-5.2.3\lib\log4j-api-2.18.0.jar;D:\Apache POI\poi-bin-5.2.3\poi-scratchpad-5.2.3.jar;C:\Users\PC\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-controls\20\javafx-controls-20-win.jar;C:\Users\PC\.m2\repository\org\apache\poi\poi\5.2.3\poi-5.2.3.jar;D:\Apache POI\poi-bin-5.2.3\poi-5.2.3.jar;C:\Users\PC\IdeaProjects\IA_real\target\classes;C:\Users\PC\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-collections4\4.4\commons-collections4-4.4.jar;D:\Apache POI\poi-bin-5.2.3\lib\commons-collections4-4.4.jar;C:\Users\PC\.m2\repository\org\apache\xmlbeans\xmlbeans\5.1.1\xmlbeans-5.1.1.jar;D:\Apache POI\poi-bin-5.2.3\ooxml-lib\xmlbeans-5.1.1.jar;C:\Users\PC\.m2\repository\commons-io\commons-io\2.11.0\commons-io-2.11.0.jar;D:\Apache POI\poi-bin-5.2.3\lib\commons-io-2.11.0.jar;C:\Users\PC\.m2\repository\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.15\commons-codec-1.15.jar;D:\Apache POI\poi-bin-5.2.3\lib\commons-codec-1.15.jar;C:\Users\PC\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-base\20\javafx-base-20-win.jar;C:\Users\PC\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-compress\1.21\commons-compress-1.21.jar;D:\Apache POI\poi-bin-5.2.3\ooxml-lib\commons-compress-1.21.jar;C:\Users\PC\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-math3\3.6.1\commons-math3-3.6.1.jar;D:\Apache POI\poi-bin-5.2.3\lib\commons-math3-3.6.1.jar;C:\Users\PC\.m2\repository\com\zaxxer\SparseBitSet\1.2\SparseBitSet-1.2.jar;D:\Apache POI\poi-bin-5.2.3\lib\SparseBitSet-1.2.jar" -m com.example.ia_real/com.example.ia_real.Main
No
Sept 11, 2023 8:32:39 PM javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement processValue
WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 20.0.1 by JavaFX runtime of version 20
ERROR StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation. Please add log4j-core to the classpath. Using SimpleLogger to log to the console...
Sept 11, 2023 8:32:42 PM javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement processValue
WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 20.0.1 by JavaFX runtime of version 20
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml@20/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1858)
    at javafx.fxml@20/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1726)
    at javafx.base@20/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at javafx.base@20/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:232)
    at javafx.base@20/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:189)
    at javafx.base@20/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base@20/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base@20/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@20/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@20/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@20/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@20/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@20/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base@20/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.base@20/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics@20/javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8944)
    at javafx.controls@20/javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:203)
    at javafx.controls@20/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:207)
    at javafx.controls@20/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
    at javafx.base@20/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:247)
    at javafx.base@20/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at javafx.base@20/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:232)
    at javafx.base@20/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:189)
    at javafx.base@20/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base@20/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base@20/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@20/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@20/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@20/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@20/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@20/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base@20/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base@20/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics@20/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3980)
    at javafx.graphics@20/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1890)
    at javafx.graphics@20/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2704)
    at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:411)
    at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:301)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400)
    at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:450)
    at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:424)
    at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:449)
    at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:551)
    at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:185)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:116)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:72)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at javafx.base@20/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:270)
    at javafx.fxml@20/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:84)
    at javafx.fxml@20/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1855)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.base/java.io.File.<init>(File.java:278)
    at com.example.ia_real/com.example.ia_real.Deadline.<init>(Deadline.java:30)
    at com.example.ia_real/com.example.ia_real.DeadlineController.<init>(DeadlineController.java:50)
    at com.example.ia_real/com.example.ia_real.DLMenuController.init(DLMenuController.java:46)
    at com.example.ia_real/com.example.ia_real.Controller.onViewAllClick(Controller.java:108)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    ... 53 more

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: You're calling `new Deadline(path)`, which in turn calls `new File(path)` before `path` has been set, which causes the null pointer exception (`path` is null). This just looks strange and convoluted. I don't see anywhere where you actually associate the controller instances with the FXML.

Comment: I see, I'll fix it. In the meantime, have you spotted any errors with the actual approach that I am using?

Comment: Yes: the immediate cause of the error is that `path` is null when you call `new Deadline(path)`, as I previously mentioned. But see the answer for a complete approach.

Comment: Off-topic: I would recommend structuring your application better. Your `Deadline` class really should only contain data (id, name, subject, onTime, late, na). Currently it is cluttered up with lots of Apache POI code which (I'm guessing) reads data from and saves it to an Excel sheet. That should be factored out into separate classes: it has nothing to do with the JavaFX part of the application.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2):

The basic structure here is to define your `DeadlineController` class with a

```
setDeadline(Deadline deadline) { ... }
```

method, which takes the `Deadline` instance to be displayed. Anything that depends on the deadline needs to be done as a result of calling that method, and not before. See [Passing Parameters JavaFX FXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml) for more details.

In your code, you have a `passPath(String path)` method that sets the `path` (not exactly sure what that is doing). However you have

```
Deadline dl = new Deadline(path);
```

as an instance variable, which will be called before there is a chance to call `passPath(...)`. The `path` variable will be `null` at that point, and so you get the null pointer exception.

Here is a greatly simplified, but complete, application that demonstrates loading multiple copies of an FXML file with configurable values, dynamically depending on user input:

Deadline.java

```
package org.jamesd.examples.multiplepanes;

import java.time.LocalDate;

public class Deadline {
    private final String task;
    private final LocalDate dueDate;

    public String getTask() {
        return task;
    }

    public LocalDate getDueDate() {
        return dueDate;
    }

    public Deadline(String task, LocalDate dueDate) {
        this.task = task;
        this.dueDate = dueDate;
    }
}
```

DeadlineView.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<VBox xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx"
      xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
      fx:controller="org.jamesd.examples.multiplepanes.DeadlineController"
      styleClass="deadline"
      spacing="5">
    <padding><Insets topRightBottomLeft="20"></Insets></padding>
    <Label fx:id="taskLabel"/>
    <Label fx:id="dueDateLabel"/>
</VBox>
```

DeadlineController.java

```
package org.jamesd.examples.multiplepanes;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class DeadlineController {

    @FXML
    private Label taskLabel;
    @FXML
    private Label dueDateLabel;

    private final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMMM YYYY");

    private Deadline deadline ;
    public void setDeadline(Deadline deadline) {
        this.deadline = deadline;
        taskLabel.setText(deadline.getTask());
        dueDateLabel.setText(formatter.format(deadline.getDueDate()));
    }
    public Deadline getDeadline() {
        return deadline;
    }
}
```

Menu.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Spinner?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.TilePane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<BorderPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx"
            xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
            fx:controller="org.jamesd.examples.multiplepanes.MenuController"
            >

    <left>
        <VBox spacing="5">
            <padding><Insets topRightBottomLeft="10"/></padding>
            <HBox spacing="5">
                <Label text = "Number of deadlines:"/>
                <Spinner fx:id="numDeadlinesSpinner">

                </Spinner>
            </HBox>
            <Button text="Generate" onAction="#generateDeadlines"/>
        </VBox>
    </left>
    <center>
        <TilePane fx:id="deadlinePane"/>
    </center>
</BorderPane>
```

MenuController.java

```
package org.jamesd.examples.multiplepanes;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.control.Spinner;
import javafx.scene.control.SpinnerValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.TilePane;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Random;

public class MenuController {
    @FXML
    private TilePane deadlinePane ;
    @FXML
    private Spinner<Integer> numDeadlinesSpinner ;

    private final Random rng = new Random();

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        numDeadlinesSpinner.setValueFactory(new SpinnerValueFactory.IntegerSpinnerValueFactory(1, 10, 5));
    }

    public void generateDeadlines() throws IOException {
        deadlinePane.getChildren().clear();
        int numDeadlines = numDeadlinesSpinner.getValue();
        for (int i = 0 ; i < numDeadlines ; i++) {
            String task = "Task " + (i+1);
            LocalDate dueDate = LocalDate.now().plusDays(rng.nextInt(5));
            Deadline deadline = new Deadline(task, dueDate);

            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(DeadlineController.class.getResource("DeadlineView.fxml"));
            Parent deadlineView = loader.load();
            DeadlineController deadlineController = loader.getController();
            deadlineController.setDeadline(deadline);
            deadlinePane.getChildren().add(deadlineView);
        }
    }
}
```

DeadlineApplication.java

```
package org.jamesd.examples.multiplepanes;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class DeadlineApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(DeadlineApplication.class.getResource("Menu.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load(), 800, 500);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```